# Is Relational Algebra under ($\times$) cartesian product a group?

Tags: group-theory, relation-algebra

I am just curios about about is that Relational Algebra under ($\times$) cartesian product count as a group ?

Since, let $A, B, C$ be three relations (tables)
$A \times (B \times C) = (A \times B) \times C$

But the thing is $I$ don't know if there exist an Identity relation (table) $I$, such that $A \times I = A$ and there exist a relation (table) X (which X is inverse relation (table) of A) denote $A \times X = X \times A = I$

My guess is that I = $\phi$ which is the empty relation (table) but I am not sure if this holds.

So, is there really exists an $I$ that make the Relational Algebra under ($\times$) cartesian product a group.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, $\varnothing$ is not an identity, as $A\times\varnothing=\varnothing$ for all $A$ (which already shows you that the structure you have cannot be a group).

Comment: Well, does there exists an $I$ that can make relation algebra a group ?

Comment: No, because in a group, the equation $xg=g$ can have only one solution for each $g$, namely $x=e$, and you have multiple solutions to that equation when $g=\varnothing$. So it doesn't matter whether there is an identity object, you **cannot** have a group.

Comment: What about the space $\{w\}$ for a single element.  The thing is this $(A\times B)\times C\ne A\times (B\times C)$ but it is isomorphic.  And $A\times \{w\}$ is isomorphic to $A$.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see that looking at relations gives anything more than looking at sets in general, so let's just consider general sets.

As [Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin) already has written, we do not have a group, since the element $\emptyset$ satisfying $X \times \emptyset = \emptyset = \emptyset \times X$ for any set $X$ is not invertible.

Also, since $|X \times Y| = |X| |Y|$ when $X$ and $Y$ are finite ($|X|$ denotes the number of elements in $X$), we cannot solve for example $A \times X = B$ if $|A| = 3$ and $|B| = 5$. There are no sets with a fractional number (e.g. $5/3$) of elements.

Some other properties are valid, though, at least under equivalence:

We can identify $(X \times Y) \times Z$ and $X \times (Y \times Z)$ by identifying $((x,y), z)$ with $(x,(y,z))$, thereby getting *associativity*.

We also have a multiplicative *identity* if we introduce some special element $\perp$ and identify $\{\perp\} \times X$ and $X \times \{\perp\}$ with $X$.

This gives use a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).